N54 Engine Block Surface (Rebuild)
back again. Finally got the right head gasket they sent me two wrong ones. I ended up just getting it from the dealer. Anyways after all that I went to take a last look and clean the block. I noticed a very small spot on the cylinder wall. My finger does catch it slightly. Head gasket is an MLS. Wondering if this an issue ?



Thank you for the help!

Two scenarios:
If there is material sticking up, you'll need to knock it down even with the flat of the mating surface. You can do this with a very flat piece of board and a very fine grit of sandpaper (ie: 600 grit or finer). You could also use a flat stone (I forget their actual name). The stone I'm talking about is a precision stone which is machined flat and comes in a pair. You run one of them across the surface and it will take the small raised bit off to make the surface flat again.
If this is a divot without anything sticking up, there'll be no issue. The reason is, there is plenty of sealing surface between water jacket and cylinder bore for there to be no issue.

My bmw grind stone did the trick !

Technically that is part of the deck of the block. Have you already had the block deck surfaced by a reputable machine shop? Obviously can’t take off a whole lot of material otherwise you will have to take the same material off of valve stems to account for it.

If it’s deeper or larger than a minor imperfection, it could affect the seal. Performing a pressure test after installation to check for leaks just in case.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
